# How to add elements to BSONArray?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have initiated an empty `BSONArray` an the used the `add` function to add some `BSONDocument`s but BSONArray stays empty

Here is some sample code

```
  var parameters = BSONArray()
  parameters add BSONDocument("$limit" -> limit)
```

The limit document is just not added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `BSONArray` is immutable and the `add` operation is returning a new array.
Try:

```
var parameters = BSONArray()
parameters = parameters add BSONDocument("$limit" -> limit)
```

Comment: I checked documentation one more time and found that `add` just makes a copy with the new data